# Inconsistency between definition of machine learning and popular usage

Tags: machine-learning, definition

Wikipedia defines machine learning as "the scientific study of algorithms and statistical models that computer systems use to progressively improve their performance on a specific task".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning

However, most textbooks about machine learning don't show exactly how to train an algorithm to "progressively improve their performance".  They simply show how to train it to do a task, but they don't show how to train it to improve its performance without being explicitly programmed to do so. I have read Hastie et al.'s "The Elements of Statistical Learning", Bishop's "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning", and Murphy's "Machine Learning: a Probabilistic Perspective", and none of them show how to improve an algorithm's performance over successive iterations.

Am I wrong to make this observation?  If so, what am I missing or misunderstanding?

Comment: I think the iterative behaviour in the definition is referring to the fact that most of the time an optimisation algorithm is used. And indeed, when you read Bishop, it explains the relevant optimisation procedure’s (Expectation-Maximisation, Stochastic Gradient Descent, etc.) iterative steps.

Comment: Using an optimization algorithm does not imply that the machine-learning technique itself is learning automatically. Simple linear regression uses optimization; it uses the method of least squares. That doesn't make it a machine-learning technique.